# NodeMCU - "Регистрация в сети"

Tags: wifi, arduino, nodemcu

Если зайти в какое-то кафе, ТЦ, аэропорт, метро, то скорее всего там будет вай-фай без пароля. Но если подключиться к нему со смартфона на андроид, например, вылезет уведомление примерно следущего содержания: "Регистрация в сети" или "Необходима авторизация". Если кликнуть по нему, открывается веб-браузер со страницей на локальной сети, в которой нужно получить СМС/прочие прелести авторизации. Как реализовать это не имея доступа к устройству, которое подключится к сети, на NodeMCU (в режиме точки доступа), без стороннего железа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется [Captive Portal](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal). Суть такова. На устройстве поднимается DNS и DHCP сервера. При первом подключении клиента DNS отправляет на любой запрос адрес локальной страницы авторизации. Как только авторизация произведена DNS сервер перенаправляет все запросы от зарегистрированного клиента к внешнему реальному DNS.

Соответственно на устройстве нужно поднять DNS, DHCP и Web (минимальный) и плюс устройство должно иметь еще один канал для доступа к Интернет.